# Groovy script create a string same name as predefined variable and return it

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

Hi everyone I am trying to run below code in groovy webconsole:

```
​// Static content examples. These lists can be generated dynamically as an alternative.
List STAGE_ALL = ["aceapp01","aceapp02","aceapp03","acemgt01"]

String allclusters = 'STAGE_ALL'
String ServerType= 'ALL'

if (ServerType == 'ALL') {
  return allclusters
} else {
  return default_item
}
```

In this when I do return allclusters it gives me STAGE_ALL whereas I want value under STAGE_ALL that is the list which I predefined [aceapp01, aceapp02, aceapp03, acemgt01]. This I get when I return STAGE_ALL list specifically.

Comment: Why can't you return `STAGE_ALL`? If you want to identify data by a key you want an object or map or something.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying its because I will have multiple clusters like 1,2,3,4,5,6 and I want to append the name 1_stage_all, 2_stage_all and then return the values. Otherwise I would need to use multiple If-else conditions, i wanted to define all cluster lists above and then have a generic if-else condition

Comment: If you want to identify data by a key you want an object or map or something.